# ComboBox crash WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, crash

Here is my XAML and C# codes. My app crashes when i choose variant in ComboBox.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="q2" Text="Тип відповіді" SelectionChanged="q2_SelectionChanged">
            <TextBlock>Одна відповідь</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Декілька відповідей</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Відповідність</TextBlock>
        </ComboBox>
```

C#:

```
private string select;
private void q2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
            ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem;
            select = selectedItem.Content.ToString();
        }
```

It crashes on this line:

```
ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem;
```

Where is the problem could be?
Thanks for help.

Comment: use ComboBoxItem instead of TextBlock: `<ComboBoxItem>Одна відповідь</ComboBoxItem>` instead of `<TextBlock>Одна відповідь</TextBlock>`, etc

Comment: Please run under a debugger and post the exception details of `It crashes on this line` here.

Comment: @ASh, thank you very much, now it works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComboBoxItem instead of TextBlock: `<ComboBoxItem>Одна відповідь</ComboBoxItem>` instead of Одна відповідь`</TextBlock>` helped me. Thaks to ASh